# Hide dialog automatically after some seconds

Tags: jquery, dialog, opencart

I have read a lot of answers about how to hide a dialog after seconds in some many ways. However I can't get this work with my example.

I am using an opencart plugin that show a DIV after you add a product in the cart but is stay there and only close when user click on "continue shopping". I want that this DIV close automatically after 5 seconds.

I have tried setTimeout, delay etc. and nothing works... so I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

The code is this:

```
$('#cart-total').html(json['total']); 
$('<div id="slidecart-success">'+json["confirmation"]+'</div>').
    dialog({
        autoOpen : true,
        modal: true,
        width : 480,
        resizable: false,                   
        title : cart_title,
        buttons: [{
            text: cart_checkout,
            click: function() { location = 'index.php?route=checkout/simplecheckout'; }
        },{
            text: pop_continue,
            click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }],                 
        dialogClass: "slidecart-success",
        create:function(){
            $("#slidecart-success-confirm").bind("click", 
                function(){
                    $('#slidecart-success').dialog('close');
                }
            );
        },
        close: function(){
            $("#slidecart-success-confirm").unbind("click"); 
            $('#slidecart-success').remove();
        }
    });
```

Can somebody help me?

**EDIT:**

I am trying also with that without success:

```
if (json['success']) {

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
// Start edit by Best-Byte //   
                $('<div id="slidecart-success">'+json["confirmation"]+'</div>').
                dialog({
                    autoOpen : true,
                    modal: true,
                    width : 480,
                    resizable: false,
                    title : cart_title,
          buttons: [{

        text: cart_checkout,
        click: function() { location = 'index.php?route=checkout/simplecheckout'; }
      },{
        text: pop_continue,
        click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
      }
      ],                    
                    dialogClass: "slidecart-success",
                    create:function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
    $("#slidecart-success-confirm").click();
}, 5000);
                        $("#slidecart-success-confirm").live("click", 
                            function(){
                                $('#slidecart-success').dialog('close');
                            }
                        );
                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

i you are not going to cancel auto close try this code

```
var dialog = $("<div/>", {
    id: "slidecart-success"
    html: json.confirmation
}).dialog({
    autoOpen : true,
    modal: true,
    width : 480,
    resizable: false,                   
    title : cart_title,
    buttons: [{
        text: cart_checkout,
        click: function() { location = "index.php?route=checkout/simplecheckout"; }
    },{
        text: pop_continue,
        click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
    }],                  
    dialogClass: "slidecart-success",
    open: function() { 
        setTimeout(function(){
            dialog.dialog("close");
        }, 5000);
    }, 
    close: function() {
        // its better to destroy dialog rather than remove node 
        dialog.destroy();
    }
}); 

// you can move this to outer scope 
// and it will close any opened dialog
$("#slidecart-success-confirm").on("click",function(){
    dialog && dialog.dialog("close");
});
```

Comment: Looks like is not doing anything with that: dialogClass: "slidecart-success",
     create:function(){
    $("#slidecart-success-confirm").bind("click", function(){
        $('#slidecart-success').dialog('close');
    }).delay(5000).click();
},
     close: function(){
      $("#slidecart-success-confirm").unbind("click");  right?

Comment: ups. sorry this is code for open callback like this open: function() { $("#slidecart-success-confirm").delay(5000).click(); }

Comment: or even more simplier open: function() { $('#slidecart-success').delay(5000).dialog('close'); }

Comment: Still not working with this: dialogClass: "slidecart-success",
     create:function() { $('#slidecart-success').delay(5000).dialog('close'); },
     close: function(){
      $("#slidecart-success-confirm").unbind("click"); 
      $('#slidecart-success').remove();
     }
    });

Comment: dialogClass: "slidecart-success",
     open: function() { $('#slidecart-success').delay(5000).dialog('close');},
     close: function(){
      $("#slidecart-success-confirm").unbind("click"); 
      $('#slidecart-success').remove(); nothing... can you edit your answer with the complete code you think should work with my example of the first message? Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$('#cart-total').html(json['total']); 
$('<div id="slidecart-success">'+json["confirmation"]+'</div>').
    dialog({ /* ... */ });

setTimeout(function(){
    $("#slidecart-success-confirm").click();
}, 5000);
```

This only invokes `click` event on that confirm button after the 5 seconds timeout...

**EDIT:**

Try to change the **`bind`** function with **`live`** for that `$("#slidecart-success-confirm")` button while using that `setTimeout` from above:

```
$("#slidecart-success-confirm").live("click", 
    function(){
        $('#slidecart-success').dialog('close');
    }
);
```

By the `live` function we tell the newly created elements (not built in the DOM) with according selectors to also respond to that event (`click` in our case). Try this and if it won't work I guess I'm out of ideas...

Comment: Thank you @shadyxx still nothing... see my code edited in the first post.